# How to make a Python 2 axis slider

Tags: python

Is there a way for me to make a 2 axis slider? It would be kinda like a tkinter slider but its a box and when you go to the top right corner it would be the maximum of both axis's. if possible i would like the x axis to snap back into the middle when released, thanks?

Comment: You could cobble one together using the Canvas widget. It would take a couple dozen lines, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't look like your OS's native slider like `tkinter`'s built-in `Scale` widget does, but you can at least implement the functionality. The following creates a `Canvas`, creates a rectangle in that canvas, then allows you to click and drag anywhere inside the canvas to move the rectangle. When you let go of the mouse button, it will print the cursor's canvas coordinates. Replace the `print()` call with whatever your program needs. You can [learn more about the `Canvas` widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm) to customize its appearance and behavior.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Scale2d(object):
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=500, width=500)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.canvas.bind('<1>', self.movement) # the magic
        self.canvas.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.movement) # similar magic
        self.canvas.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', self.report) # result of magic
        self.indicator = self.canvas.create_rectangle(245,245,255,255, fill='black') # dot

    def movement(self, event): # move the dot
        self.canvas.coords(self.indicator, event.x-5, event.y-5, event.x+5, event.y+5)

    def report(self, event): # report the dot
        print(event.x, 500-event.y) # 500-event.y to invert y axis
        self.canvas.coords(self.indicator, 245, 245, 255, 255) # snap back


root = tk.Tk()
scale2d = Scale2d(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked perfectly after I changed it a bit.

Comment: If this answer was useful, you can mark it as such by clicking the check mark.